# How to implement firewall in LAN(out of users' os) like EC2 have done?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, firewall, local-area-network, tcpip

In aws ec2, users can set up **security groups** which works like a firewall, usually, firewall work behind a gateway/nat server, however, I found that firewall in EC2 works in the LAN, too.

For example, users have too instances, `A: 10.108.33.13/26`, `B: 10.108.33.18/26`, according to the `ip` and `netmask`, they are in the same LAN, however, if I put those instances in different **security groups**(and the rules block visit from different sgs), the firewall works on them.

My questions is, I think firewall works only in Layer3/4, on which ip and port were. In the LAN, traffic between hosts goes throught Layer2(by MAC address). How could it be possible to implement such firewall in a LAN?

P.S. I checked the iptables on each host and I am sure it's stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A whole bunch of the more advanced L3 switches support [ACLs](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-7514) which every packet / frame would be checked against upon entry - no matter if it would have been going to the routing engine of the switch. This way, restrictions for hosts within the same broadcast domain can be implemented rather easily, although it should be noted that the processing of ACLs is typically not as sophisticated as you would expect from a stateful packet filter (mostly because the processing logic is implemented in circuitry instead of software).

This being said, as [Amazon is virtualizing with Xen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud#Instance_types) so they would be using virtual switching / Linux bridging rather heavily and likely would have implemented their filtering within the software layer - [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/) which is capable of doing IP filtering on bridged interfaces would be a good candidate for the under-the-hood processing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is what I need and this helps me a lot.

Comment: After a quick look, I think **ebtables** should work for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ley if the post helped you, please mark it "as an answer" by checking the mark underneath the vote count field.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that at first. New to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've been reading the OpenStack nova implementations.

Then I found that if `libvirt` were used, the firewall above can be easily implemented using the `nwfilter` mechanism `libvirt` has implemented.

Detailed information can be found at http://libvirt.org/firewall.html, it explans how it was implemented, and as @syneticon-dj mentioned, it used a combination of `ebtables`, `iptables` and `ip6tables`.